# Unable to pass the value of ID in an update MySql query in the code

Tags: php, mysql

I need to pass the value of a drop down list to an already existing table, I've tried a simple MySql query which works properly in the MySQL SQL console.

Here is the query which I need to run: `update Trial set Status = 'Test Status' where id = '123'`

When I try to run this query it runs into variable issues as it's unavailable to get the value of ID from the row.

Below are two Queries, the first one fetches all the data, and the second which is not proper is the one which needs to update the value of the drop down list to the already existing table where the ID mathches. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cotactform";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, email, phone, Status,Url, datetime FROM Trial";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr style='text-align:center;'><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td><td>". $row["phone"]. "</td><td>". $row["Url"]. "</td><td>". $row["datetime"]. "</td><form method='get' action='displaydata.php'><td><select name='Status'><option>--Select Status--</option><option value='valid'>Valid</option><option value='invalid'>Invalid</option><option value='followup'>FollowUp</option></select><button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button></form></td> <td>". $row["Status"]."</td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}




  if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $Status=$_GET['Status'];

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    // The query to update the Status
    $ins="update Trial set Status = '$Status' where id = 'id'";
    if($ins)
    {
        echo "<br>".$Status."inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Edit Updated for adding the hidden field:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr style='text-align:center;'><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td><td>". $row["phone"]. "</td><td>". $row["Url"]. "</td><td>". $row["datetime"]. "</td><form method='get' action='displaydata.php'><td><select type='hidden' name=".$row["id"]."><option>--Select Status--</option><option value='valid'>Valid</option><option value='invalid'>Invalid</option><option value='followup'>FollowUp</option></select><button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button></form></td> <td>". $row["Status"]."</td></tr>";
    }
```

Second query check:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $Status=$_GET['Status'];


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
     //$id=$_GET['id'];
     //$Status=$_GET['Status'];

    $ins = "update Trial set Status = '" . $Status ."' where id = '".$id."'";
    $run = $conn->query($ins);
    if($ins)
    {
        echo "<br>".$Status."inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: Second query is __never run__.

Comment: `mysql_error` when using `mysqli`, two connections. Mess.

Comment: i didnt find mysql_query or mysqli_query execution, second you r mixing mysql and mysqli, third i suggest you to use integer as a status not string

Comment: Also mind the SQL injection which is possible in the update query.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? That's a lot of code, and most of it (like echoing some table lines) seems out of scope for your question

Comment: accepting the correct answer will help to future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the **update** query -

```
$ins = "update Trial set Status = " . $Status ." where id = 123";
```

Naturally, if you can obtain the 'id' and store it an a variable then you replace the hardcoded id (123) by `$id` (say), it would become -

```
$ins = "update Trial set Status = " . $Status ." where id = " . $id;
```

Comment: Mind the SQL injections, which is at top to hack webapplications

Comment: but $status is string not integer, i think OP just forgot to use query exection

Comment: Is there any way to save the id as a variable, currently it's giving the Undefined Variable error, also I will update the $status as an int

Comment: @AnjumShaikh: send ID in hidden input of form `$row["id"]` then u can use it.

Comment: @devpro I added that in the hidden input of the form but it still gives an error on the line where the second query is placed that it is a undefined variable. Should I edit and add both of the updated queries to the question above

Comment: i only see select box not any hidden in this form `<form method='get' action='displaydata.php'>`

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues in your code:

**First,** your code is wide open for SQL Injection, you can use PDO here to prevent SQL Injection.

**Second,** i didnt see query execution with your `UPDATE` query.

**Third,** this is just a suggestion, use integer for multiple status instead of Complete Word or String.

**Fourth,** Don't know what are you doing with your `<form>`, you are using `hidden` attribute with `<select>` box which is not required to get `ID`.

**Fifth,**  using `mysql_error()` means, you are mixing mysqli and mysql together.

**For getting ID,** you need to modify your `<form>` as:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="your ID">
   <select>
     <option></option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Then, you can get this hidden `ID` in your query as `$id = $_GET['id']`.

**Side Note:** this is very important, you are using `<form>` method `GET` for UPDATE query, you must need to prevent your code with SQL Injection.

Some References:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)